# How to send email using SMTP server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, smtp

mailers/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp  
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :adress => 'myemail@gmail.com',
 :port => 25,
 :authentication => :login,
 :user_name => 'myemail',
 :password => 'secret'
}
```

Here is my Mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
def welcome_email(name, email, subject, question)
@recipients   = email
@from         = "myemail@gmail.com"
headers         "Reply-to" => "myemail0@gmail.com"
@subject      = "Welcome to MyDomain"
@sent_on      = Time.now
@content_type = "text/html"
#body[:username]  = name
mail(:to => email, :subject => subject, :from => 'myemail@gmail.com')
end
end
```

Have this error:
504 5.3.3 AUTH mechanism LOGIN not available

Please help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you expecting to happen and what error/unexpected outcome are you getting?

Comment: Why do you want to get the columns? How are you going to render those columns? Also, the title of your question is misleading.

Comment: Try to edit your question to make it more informative

Comment: Tried reading this ? `http://evilrockhopper.com/2009/06/ruby-on-rails-smtp-mailer-sending-mail/` and this `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html`

Comment: What did this have to do with an SMTP server?

Comment: what does the question have to do with "intall smtp server" ? what do you expect the dashboard method to return ?

Comment: sorry...I was stuck in questions. Question was edited.

Comment: setup your smtp on `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb` referensi [try this](http://www.railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 1):

I use something along these lines to talk with gmail

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp  
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 :port => 587,
 :authentication => 'plain',
 :user_name => 'myemail',
 :password => 'secret',
 :enable_starttls_auto => true,
 :domain => 'gmail.com'
}
```